# Serve static webroot/index.html data on non-existing routes on Vert.x Web Router

Tags: java, rest, web, routes, vert.x

**Scenario:**

- I have placed my static data on webroot/* folder location and server
  serves those data on request.
- I have lots of routes for routing APIs.

**Router's Code:**

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

router.route("/api/login/account").handler((RoutingContext ctx) -> {
  // Handler is here
});
router.route("/api/currentUser").handler(ctx -> {
  // Handler is here
});
router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());
router.route("/*").hanler(StaticHandler.create("webroot/index.html"));
```

**Folder webroot has following files:**

- index.css
- index.html
- image/image.jpg

**Problem:**

- Need to serve webroot/index.html file on routing mismatch **(it is not working; returning value **'Resource not found'**)**: if I request the data for /xyz/abc then webroot/index.html should be served.
- Need to serve other static files as it's requested parameter **(it is working)**: if I request the data for /index.css then webroot/index.css should be served.
- Need to response data for API request **(it is working)**: if I request the data for /api/login/account then it should respond.

Where I missed the here? And what would be the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a last handler that sends the file you want when everything fails. E.g.:

```
ctx.response().sendFile('webroot/index.html');
```

Don't forget to add the headers you might need, for example caching directives, location, content type...

Comment: Thank you, appreciated very much. After adding following code it's working as I needed:

router.route("/*").handler(ctx -> {
            ctx.response().sendFile("webroot/index.html");});

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you answer questions on a mobile just out of your head! :-)